# Using kernel debug symbols on Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, qemu, debug-symbols

I see that I can install packages that contain the kernel debug symbols in Ubuntu as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197016/how-to-install-a-package-that-contains-ubuntu-kernel-debug-symbols). Is it possible to do the same for Raspberry pi? I'd really like to have kernel symbols for the raspbian that I'm running in QEMU.

Comment: if you are building your own kernel then you may want to look into this link http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/basicmodule/

Comment: @askb Hi, I'm not building my own kernel. Would it be possible to install the debug symbols for the kernel alone somehow? It seems to be possible in the case of Ubuntu as shown in the link above.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm currently looking for the debug symbols and I'm at a loss.